# Why hibernate throws "data truncation-data too long for coloumn 'a' at row 1”?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using Spring and hibernate. I created Entity class.

I created new variable in entity class.

I restart the server and checked

It throws

"Nested execution error  "

and 
"data truncation-data too long for coloumn 'assigned_users' at row 1”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I got answer for questions after long time spent in google.

It is simple mistake I made. The new entity variable was not have @coloumn Annotations.

So when I checked in table the datatype stored as tiny BLOB.

SO I set @ Coloumn annotations and realtionship with specific coloumn..

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "assigned_user")

Its Working fine...